# htaccess valid or not

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, meta, errordocument

i've a htaccess where i want to 
- hide contents of folders -> this one ok
- redirection where we're in the wrong link -> this one is ok
- solve the problem of validator with the chrome meta -> this one i'm not sure

Here is my htacces, is it correct ?

```
options -indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404/index.php


<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
BrowserMatch MSIE ie
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: "solve the problem of validator with the chrome meta" — The reason the validator complains about the chrome meta is because the chrome meta is *pointless*. Google Chrome Frame is dead.

Comment: and so, i don't need to put that <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /> on my html page ? and i can remove <filesmatch> bloc ?